# Insert into database when processing large json

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to import data into SQL database from large json file. 
Current implementation is read line by line using node.js readable stream and then pause stream do async insert using knex.js.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('./knexfile')[environment];
const knex = require('knex')(config);

const stream = fs.createReadStream('books.json', {encoding: 'utf8'})

stream
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
  .on('data', (data) => {
        stream.pause();

        knex('books').insert(data)
              .then((res) => {
                    stream.resume()
                    console.log(res)
              })
  });
```

The problem with this approach that with each insert amount of connection grows and knex doesn't drop sql connection after each insert.

```
  knex:pool INFO pool sqlite3:sqlite3:client0 - dispense() clients=956 available=0 +1ms
```

Is there any proper way insert data using streams from large json?

Comment: I don't have much experience with sqlite3 or knex but i'm sure knex won't be efficient at inserting thousands of rows one-by-one. What you may want to look at is using sqlite3 native driver and do **bulk insert** using transanctions (note it's much slower w/o transactions since each insert is treated as transaction which adds unwanted overhead) try to search for *"nodejs sqlite3 bulk insert"*

Comment: When I did this in Python, I would encounter similar problem. Normally every N entries I flesh and close the cursor and connection and open a new set.

Comment: @Molda knex supports also batch insert, but when doing this kind of one time import it usually doesn't matter if it takes 500ms or 5 seconds. Other thing is that doing inserts inside single transaction may be also slower, since DB has to keep track of changes and be ready to allow rolling them back if necessary. It is impossible to say if there is speed benefit without trying it out. Anyways using transaction isn't bad idea to be able to rollback everything if something goes wrong, but in this case it probably doesn't matter unless there is existing data in sqlite base.

Comment: @plugataryov-yura I wasn't able to reproduce this with simple for-loop triggering 1000 concurrent queries (count did first get up, but then it did do back down)... I'll try it with your code later. What is your knex version and sqlite configuration?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/strangeworks/5baea8cd355b6657bdcb8cc60c143303 here is dummy PoC app to reproduce this issue, generate json 10k records and use batch-insert.js to reproduce